# Ubuntu showing 13.7 GB of RAM when I have 16 GB

Tags: ram, bios

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10. I have a system with 16 gigabytes of DDR4 RAM.

Ubuntu itself only shows that I have 13.7 gigabytes of ram:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           13Gi        10Gi       699Mi       284Mi       2.4Gi       2.5Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       384Mi       1.6Gi
```

However, the BIOS is reporting 16 GB:

```
tim@tim-System-Product-Name:/$ sudo dmidecode | grep Size | grep MB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
```

I figured that maybe the Kernel is reserving a large amount of RAM, but it seems that is only true for about 400 MB of the usage:

```
tim@tim-System-Product-Name:/$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Slab
Slab:             427340 kB
```

About 2 GB of RAM is still unaccounted for.

I'm trying to run a pretty resource-intensive virtualization setup with KVM, and so that missing 2 Gigabytes is pretty essential. I'd like to be able to dedicate 8 Gigabytes to my virtual machine for my specific use case, but as it stands that leaves the host very little wiggle room when the KVM machine is active.

My RAM is properly seated, and alternately spaced.

If I need to buy another stick of RAM, I'm happy to do so, but the fact that so much of it is being obscured feels like a waste, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what the system is using it for.

Comment: Are you using integrated graphics chip? If so then a portion might be allocated for graphics. What do `dmesg | grep -i drm` and `dmesg | grep e820` say? I'm experiencing a similar issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254226/how-to-free-up-ram-a-lot-is-reserved-for-pci-devices-after-ram-upgrade-6-7-gb)